# Firebase firestore pricing for querying

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Assume that i have 20 documents in a collection, and each document has a field that contains the number of views for querying. Example below

```
collection
     |_document
             |_views: 100
     |_document
             |_views: 600
     |_document
             |_views: 10
```

Later i query the documents to return top 5 highest views. Now my question is, will i be charged for 20 document reads or 5 document reads

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This Firestore documentation [item](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations) (Section "Listening to query results") will give you the answer:

> When you listen to the results of a query, you are charged for a read each time a document in the result set is added or updated. You are also charged for a read when a document is removed from the result set because the document has changed. (In contrast, when a document is deleted, you are not charged for a read.)
>
> Also, if the listener is disconnected for more than 30 minutes (for
>   example, if the user goes offline), you will be charged for reads as
>   if you had issued a brand-new query.

In other words, if your query limits the number of documents returned to 5 (e.g. with `limit()`, as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data)), you will only pay for 5 document reads (unless you are using a listener -and not get()- and a document is created/modified/deleted and changes the top 5 or unless you encounter the 30 minutes disconnection specific case mentioned above).

On the other hand, if you filter the top 5 docs on the client-side, after receiving the entire set of documents, you will obviously be charged for the full set.

Comment: So what you are saying is, even if i have 200 documents and the query goes through all the 200 document and i limit to 5 (not done on the client-side), i only get charged for the 5 reads?

Comment: Yes, indeed. If for example you do a query like `documentsCollectionRef.orderBy("views", "desc").limit(5).get().then(...)` you will pay for 5 reads.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Can you give us a link where you've found this explicitly written? I have a case where I must find a single document in 50k document collection, does that mean that I'll be charged only for a single request? Thanks!

Comment: @SebastijanDumančić If you make a Firestore query to get this doc, then yes you will be charged for one read only. Have a look at the official following video https://youtu.be/6NegFl9p_sE at 2:20. It is the video that is embedded in the doc I refer to in my answer. (If, on the other hand, you do the filter on the front end then you would pay for the entire set of docs. Of course, this is not recommended, for price and also for performance)

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Thanks, I'll look into it a bit more.